# Command "cim" is not defined

Tags: drush

I'm getting the following error while running `drush cim` on a new environment to import the configurations as they exist in the repo:

`Command "cim" is not defined`

also:

`Command "config:import" is not defined`

`Command "config:export" is not defined`

`Command "config:cex" is not defined`

In trying to search for help online, nearly all of the results include the string "Drush was unable to query the database", which is NOT in my error, and I'm perplexed as to why I'm not getting better results and starting this post in the meantime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although [this post](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3464) shows the exact same error, it was for a different purpose, but it reminded me to add the debug flag to the command, making `drush cim --debug`. This showed a stack trace that included *The config sync directory is not defined in `$settings["config_sync_directory"]`*. Which is weird, because it is defined, except for a typo in the string! Fixing that typo made everything work as normal, but the error was so misleading that I'm writing it up for anyone else in the same predicament.